# Add client side handler from content page to master page control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, events, master-pages, content-pages

I have a requirement for four similar pages in an ASP.Net webforms application. All four pages will have a header with a dropdown and two buttons. I intend to use a master page for this header and then content pages for each of the different pages I need to produce. My master looks like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Processing.master.cs" Inherits="MyProject.Processing" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link href="../../Stylesheets/Processing.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script language="javascript" src="../../Scripts/js/Processing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="ProcessingForm" height="100%" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="titleLabel" runat="server" class="bold"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="storeLabel" Text="Store:" />
        <asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="storesDataSource" TypeName="MyProject.Processing"
            SelectMethod="GetStoresDataSource">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="UserName" QueryStringField="eUserName" DefaultValue="" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="storeDropdown" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="storeDropdown_SelectedIndexChanged"
            AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataSourceID="storesDataSource" DataTextField="Display"
            DataValueField="Number">
            <asp:ListItem />
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="refreshButton" runat="server" Text="Refresh" OnClick="refreshButton_Click" />
        <%-- ************************************************************************************--%>
        <%-- This is the button that I want to add client side behaviour to from my content pages--%>
        <%-- ************************************************************************************--%>
        <asp:Button ID="processButton" runat="server" Text="Process" OnClick="processButton_Click"
            OnClientClick="DoStuff();" />
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="GridDiv" runat="server" /> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the Processing.master.cs I've defined an event that the content pages can subscribe to to react when the dropdown changes:

```
public delegate void StoreChangedHandler(object sender, string selectedValue);
public event StoreChangedHandler OnStoreChanged;

protected void storeDropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OnStoreChanged != null)
    {
        OnStoreChanged(sender, ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue);
    }
}
```

So the content page's OnLoad contains:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Processing)Master).OnStoreChanged += StockRoomWithMaster_OnSomethingSelected;
}

void StockRoomWithMaster_OnSomethingSelected(object sender, string selectedValue)
{
    this.stockReceiptGridView.DataBind();
}
```

What is the best way to do this same strategy for the client side `DoStuff()` function call that occurs when the processButton control is clicked? I could declare a global variable in the Processing.js file and in the content page assign it to a function:

Processing.js:

```
var processButtonClickedHandler;

function DoStuff()
{
    if (processButtonClickedHandler) {
        processButtonClickedHandler();
    }
}
```

In content page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    processButtonClickedHandler = DoSpecificStuff;
});

function DoSpecificStuff() {
    // Custom page client side stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are doing this is the best way. I have created created a test bu putting an alert in DoSpecificStuff in the same way you did and it worked good.